How to get Discord ID / Username and Life Time Paid Amount of all Discord members I have via Discord API
I need my all time all members Member Attributes lifetime_support_cents
So from all campaigns and all tiers
Plus to this I need their discord id or username - they can have multiple it is fine i need to get all
Discord has several i don’t know which is exactly users discord id or username
https://docs.patreon.com/#get-api-oauth2-v2-campaigns-campaign_id-members
https://docs.patreon.com/#fetching-a-patron-39-s-profile-info
attributes > discord_id
social_connections > discord
attributes > discord_role_ids

Nothing else
I have been struggling to get these 2 info for hours
But nothing returns
Here my so far code. If you just tell me code of api_client fetch command i can do rest
I need all time, all campaigns and all tiers data
This below code returns all null data for all members. However I have over 500 discord ids in those members. I know because I was able to see them before their recent interface update.
import os
import json
import requests
from patreon import API, OAuth

# Patreon API authentication
client_id = "client_id"
client_secret = "client_secret"
 
access_token = "access_token"
refresh_token = "refresh_token"

api_client = API(access_token)

import os
import json


# Check if results.json exists
if os.path.exists("results2.json"):
    # Load data from results.json
    with open("results.json2", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        all_patrons = json.load(file)
else:
    # Fetch all patrons
    all_patrons = {}
    cursor = None

    # Get the campaign ID
    campaign_response = api_client.fetch_campaign()
    campaign_id = campaign_response.json_data['data'][0]['id']

    while True:
        pledges_response = api_client.fetch_page_of_pledges(campaign_id, 250, cursor=cursor)
        pledges = pledges_response.data()

        for pledge in pledges:
            included_members = pledge.document.json_data.get('included', [])
            data_members = pledge.document.json_data.get('data', [])
            data_members2 = pledge.document.json_data.get('included', [])

            for member in included_members + data_members + data_members2:
                if 'attributes' in member:
                    discord_id = member['attributes'].get('discord_id')
                    discord_username = member['attributes'].get('social_connections', {}).get('discord')
                    email = member['attributes'].get('email')
                    unique_key = f"{discord_id}_{discord_username}_{email}"

                    if unique_key not in all_patrons:
                        patron_data = {
                            "email": email,
                            "discord_username": discord_username,
                            "discord_id": discord_id
                        }
                        all_patrons[unique_key] = patron_data

        print(f"Fetching {cursor}")
        cursor = api_client.extract_cursor(pledges_response)
        if not cursor:
            break

    # Convert the dictionary values to a list
    all_patrons = list(all_patrons.values())

    # Save data to results.json
    with open("results2.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        json.dump(all_patrons, file, ensure_ascii=False)

